# dialogflow, google action and webdemo

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Can you like with the Test Simulator have an embedded Google Action or use a Live chat style bot on a website with Google Actions responses? Are there any code labs or third party platforms that do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, some of the 3rd party chat windows I know of: 
- Smooch
- [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io/)

You will have to use the Payload response to send specific components (such as cards, quick replies or images)

There's also this Github repository which allows you to set Google Actions replies and it will display it in chat: 
https://github.com/mishushakov/dialogflow-web-v2

Or you can write your own in React or Vue.

Answer (score 1):

Actions on Google is the platform for Google Assistant developers and have own library and components. You can use these features and components only on Google Assistant projects, since every platform has different features and capability. If you need to create a chatbot with these kind of features, you should check platform's docs eg. Facebook, Telegram...

If you want to create a chatbot which has some rich responses, Dialogflow has own attributes such as Card, Suggestion. So, you can build your agent and integrate Dialogflow (not Google Action).

You can check [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/rich-messages) for platform and Dialogflow's response and payload ability.